# Loop through JSON feed items with set interval and replace previous item

Tags: jquery, html, json, loops, indexing

I've written some jQuery to get each item from JSON request and insert to an HTML table, this inserts it only once. I want to be able to hide the previous item and insert the next item from JSON request one at a time in a continuous loop, every 3 seconds for example. I've had a go at trying loops but I couldn't get it to work, so just asking for some help on this!

What I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/saffad/tZxKr/1/

JSON request looks like this:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
             "member_photo": {
                 "thumb_link": "foo.jpeg"
             },
             "member_name": "Daniel",
             "comment": "this is cool"
        },
        {
             "member_photo": {
                "thumb_link": "blah.jpeg"
             },
             "member_name": "John",
             "comment": "hello everyone"
        },
        ....
  ]
}
```

Comment: You are missing id that distinguish each comments. That would make your life lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

**EDIT**: Now it loops continously.

```
function displayComments(data) {
    window.nAux = data.results.length;
    $.each(data.results, function(i,item) {
        (new Image()).src = item.member_photo.thumb_link; //Preload image (optional)
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".comments").hide();
            $(".comments").find("img.thumb").attr('src', item.member_photo.thumb_link);
            $(".comments").find("td.comment").text(item.comment);
            $(".comments").find("td.name").text(item.member_name);
            $('.comments').fadeIn('slow');
            if(--window.nAux == 0) //If cycle ended...
               setTimeout(function(){ displayComments(data); }, 6000); //Start again in 6 seconds
        }, 6000*i); //Wait 6 seconds

    });
}
```

I tested it in your jsfiddle and runs ok :)

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: @At Edgar, Khan: Are you sure?.... Looking at the question/answer they don't quite match up..... Khan asked for a continuous loop whilst you just gave him a single loop delaying each item iteration. I've posted an answer that will do exactly what khan wants.

Comment: Sorry yes, i did ask for continuous loop, and realised this solution stops after single loop after accepting it, forgot to correct it. Thanks

Comment: @Khan: No problem. Did you check my one? I'm just trying to keep things right. There's nothing worse than trawling through a forum to find that the answers are no use to you.

Comment: I edited my solution, so now it loops continously as Khan asked. _I'm not going to talk bad about other people's solutions_, I just can say my solution **is simple** and very similar to the requester original code, in consecuence, **easy to mantain** and **very readable**.

Comment: @Edgar I agree your solution easier to understand, maybe because its keeping with my original code, but it helps. Thnanks

Comment: @Edgar: I bow down... That's just clever.

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = what_you_said_above;
var idx = -1;
function rotateThingy(){
  if (++idx == results.length)
    idx = 0;
  document.getElementById('yourElemId').innerHTML = results[idx].member_name;
}
setInterval('rotateThingy', 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting comments every 3 seconds, I would try to append to a div.
The comment div needs to have a distinguishing id. That id can be the id of the comment.

You might need to find the id of the last comment you processed.
Either you can store in a hidden field or some global var.

Once you have a new comment in, you append the new one.
You then hide the comment you processed last.

This should be simple.

Comment: That is good idea, I will have a go at getting the comment_id from JSON and when there is new comment, higher than the current id I can append that, is that how it would work?

Comment: I'd be careful about doing this. You could end up making a lot of requests.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer for the question doesn't do what the user actually asked for. Here is my go which does. There updated fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tZxKr/2/)

```
$.getJSON("http://api.meetup.com/2/event_comments.json/?key=4b247e365978741497368536d603830&sign=true&event_id=16827758&fields=member_photo&callback=?", displayComments);

function displayComments(data) {

    var results = data.results,
        iterator = function (array, number) {
            // This function allows you to iterated through an
            // returning the next item(s) the count determined by the             // given number from the array.
            var current = 0,
            length = array.length;

            return function () {
                end = current + number;
                var part = array.slice(current, end);
                if (end > length) {
                    end = end % length;
                    part = part.concat(array.slice(0, end));
                }
                current = end;
                return part;
            };
        },
        // Get the first commment.
        next = iterator(results,1),
        firstRun = true,
        speed = 5000,

        loadComment = function(){
        // Load the comments one by one.
            var item = next()[0],
                $commentContainer = $(".comments");
            buildComment = function(){

                $commentContainer.find("img.thumb").attr('src', item.member_photo.thumb_link);
                $commentContainer.find("td.comment").text(item.comment);
                $commentContainer.find("td.name").text(item.member_name);

                $commentContainer.fadeIn('slow');

            };
            // hide the container and populate/show on callback.
            $commentContainer.fadeOut("slow", null, buildComment);

            // Set interval after first run.
            if (firstRun){
               firstRun = false;
               setInterval(loadComment,speed);   
            }
        };

       // Load the first comment.
       loadComment();
}
```

Comment: Thanks James, that is what i wanted :)